# How do I do complex url patterns for security constraints?

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, web, web.xml

I am using the following to secure parts of my website.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>secure</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>            
    </web-resource-collection>          
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>SecureUsers</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>          
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I know I can create another security-constraint with transport-guarantee=NONE to allow certain URLs to go through without needing to be authenticated, e.g.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Insecure</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/oauth-request-consumer/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/oauth-authorize-consumers/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/oauth-request-token/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/oauth-authorization/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/oauth-access-token/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

But what if I want to allow without authentication

```
/a/b/*/d
```

but require authentication for

```
 /a/b/*/
```

Aside from putting every combination of "/a/b/*/d" in the security constraint, is there a better way? These paths are dynamic and may change over time, also, which means every time it changes I have to update the web.xml file with updated security constraints.

Is there a way to delegate the url-pattern to a class? It seems that would allow me to set it once in the web.xml and then have code that decides if the URL needs authentication.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a better way? I am also using WebSphere trust association interceptors for SSO.

Comment: It's like saying, I want to drink water but do not want to open my mouth for it. :D

Comment: Seems like Spring Security has better capability here.